# the loop applying the css property from just last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I made few divs with data-line attribute. I want to loop each divs and take the own value from data-line attribute and apply to width as % but it takes only last value and apply it all of them.

You can look at my code here.

```js
(function processLine() {
  var processBar = $('.process');
  var percent = $('.process-percent .percentage');
  //var id = setInterval(frame, 15);

  function frame() {
   var arrData = [];
   processBar.each(function() {
    var processData = $(this).data('line');
    if (arrData.indexOf(processData) !== processData) {
     arrData.push(processData);
    }
   });


   for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
     processBar.css({
      'width': arrData[i] + '%'
     });
   }

  }

  frame();
})();
```

```css
.process-bar {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 265px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
}

#sidebar-left .process-bar {
    width: 265px;
}

.process {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #aab3c3;
}

.process-percent {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    padding-right: 5%;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar-container {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar-container:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar {
    max-width: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
            border-radius: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 9px solid transparent;
 border-left: 18px solid #e4e4e4;
 border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #f9f9f9;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 120px solid #f9f9f9;
    border-top: 10px solid #f9f9f9;
    z-index: 2;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process {
    width: 70%;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
            border-radius: 0px;
    background: #f8981d;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process .bike {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    padding-right: 2%;
    line-height: 0;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 10px solid transparent;
 border-left: 20px solid #f8981d;
 border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}


.yaris-arrow-progress .lap-xp {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="yaris-arrow-progress">
<div class="process-bar-container">
        <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

            <div class="process-bar ">
                <div class="process" data-line="10">
                    <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="process-bar-container">
        <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

            <div class="process-bar ">
                <div class="process" data-line="65">
                    <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="process-bar-container">
        <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

            <div class="process-bar ">
                <div class="process" data-line="83">
                    <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="process-bar-container">
        <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

            <div class="process-bar">
                <div class="process" data-line="95">
                    <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `processBar` inside the `for` loop to update the CSS width. Since `processBar` is the collection of all the `.process` elements, when you call `.css` on it, all the elements get changed. Try to use `.eq(i)` to change only the element at the `i-th` index of that collection.

**Plus** I don't see why you're using two loops. You can apply CSS directly inside `each` (where you can use `$(this)` to target the current element:

```
function frame() {
    processBar.each(function() {
        var processData = $(this).data('line');
        $(this).css({
//        ^^^^ instead of processBar which changes the whole collection
            'width': processData + '%'
        });
    });
}
```

```js
(function processLine() {
  var processBar = $('.process');
  var percent = $('.process-percent .percentage');

  function frame() {
    processBar.each(function() {
      var processData = $(this).data('line');
      $(this).css({
        'width': processData + '%'
      });
    });
  }

  frame();
})();
```

```css
.process-bar {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 265px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#sidebar-left .process-bar {
  width: 265px;
}

.process {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #aab3c3;
}

.process-percent {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  padding-right: 5%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar-container {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar-container:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar {
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 9px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process-bar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid #f9f9f9;
  border-top: 10px solid #f9f9f9;
  z-index: 2;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process {
  width: 70%;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #f8981d;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process .bike {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  padding-right: 2%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .process::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #f8981d;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.yaris-arrow-progress .lap-xp {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="yaris-arrow-progress">
  <div class="process-bar-container">
    <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

      <div class="process-bar ">
        <div class="process" data-line="10">
          <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="process-bar-container">
    <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

      <div class="process-bar ">
        <div class="process" data-line="65">
          <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="process-bar-container">
    <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

      <div class="process-bar ">
        <div class="process" data-line="83">
          <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="process-bar-container">
    <div class="process-bar-wrapper">

      <div class="process-bar">
        <div class="process" data-line="95">
          <div class="bike"><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a very simple code. No need to write so much long functions.

```
$('.process').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).data('line');
    $(this).css('width',width+'%');
});
```

Comment: Sorry brother I did not know that you have posted the answer. Our answers are very similar.